# WPF: Show gif with ImageMagick by MemoryStream

Tags: wpf, imagemagick, gif, memorystream

I'm trying to show an animated gif through a normal **Image** control:

```
<Image Name="animationImagePlayer"/>
```

collection contains all the frames previously loaded.

```
using (MemoryStream gifStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    collection.Write(gifStream, MagickFormat.Gif);
                    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

                    bitmap.BeginInit();
                    bitmap.StreamSource = gifStream;
                    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    bitmap.EndInit();
                    bitmap.Freeze();

                    animationImagePlayer.Source = bitmap;
                }
```

I see a single frame of the sequence and no animation mechanism.
I tried to save the stream in a gif file, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: "a single frame of the sequence and no animation mechanism" is exactly what the Image element is supposed to do. Did you search the web for e.g. "wpf animated gif"?

Comment: The same solution works on winforms using a picturebox, I don't see why it shouldn't on WPF with Image

Comment: WPF and WinForms are different frameworks. If a WinForms PictureBox shows an animated GIF you can't conclude that a WPF Image element also does. It just does not.

Comment: I'm open to consider a possible answer a suggestion on the type of control to use or a generic re-elaboration of the solution using ImageMagick + MemoryStream.

Answer (score 0):

Example with PictureBox

1. You need kept open stream.

   ```
    System.IO.MemoryStream gifStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
   ```
2. In method Write() use MagickFormat.Gif else you write static image in stream

   ```
    pictureEditor.image.Write(gifStream, MagickFormat.Gif);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(gifStream);
   ```